Is there a way to fix the inconsistent colors from Unity's Unlit shaders?
I'm having issues with Unity's Unlit shaders making objects different colors from what is expected.
For example, when choosing a simple red color,
the display shows this
However, when the shader is applied to a gameobject,
it's a noticeable darker red
I tried using Unity's URP/Unlit and Unlit/Color shaders and changing the color spaces but they all resulted in the same issue.
It's pretty important that the colors are accurate for my program so any help would be appreciated.
